# How do I find the differential of these functions?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

We are given 2 functions:

1) $f: \operatorname{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb R) \to\operatorname{ Mat}_{n\times n} (\mathbb R)$, $f(A)=A^m$, $m>0$.

and

2) $g: \operatorname{GL}_n (\mathbb R) \to \operatorname{GL}_n (\mathbb R)$, 
$g(A)=A^m$, $m<0$.

Find the differential (the jacobi matrix) of these functions.

I'm having difficulties. My usual method of finding how the function effects every component doesn't seem to work.

where does $f$ send the entry in the place $(i,j)$? where does $g$? I don't know, so my usual method doesn't work here.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential is a linear application $Df(A)[\cdot]$ such that
$f(A+B)-f(A)=Df(A)[B]+o(\|B\|)$ for "small" matrices $B$. In your case $L\in \mathcal L(M_n(\Bbb R))$. i.e. it is not a matrix, but a linear application from the space of matrices to itself (it is a tensor of fourth order, if you want).

We can write $$f(A+B)-f(A)= BA^{m-1} +ABA^{m-2}+\dots+A^{m-1}B+o(\|B\|),$$
so $$ Df(A)[B]=BA^{m-1} +ABA^{m-2}+\dots+A^{m-1}B.$$

Can you now write $Dg(A)[B]$?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how you found the differential of $f$. I agree its a linear application, but how did you find it?

Comment: @OriaGruber I wrote $(A+B)^m-A^m$ and opened the brackets - note that $A$ and $B don't necessarily commute. For example, `$(A+B)^2 = A^2+AB+BA+B^2$`, etc. Then I dropped all the terms containing at least two factors of $B$,  and labelled them as $o(\|B\|)$. What was left has to form the differential.